# How do I use a button that I referenced from with library with Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I'm a newbie at using Stack Overflow so bear with me if my formatting or explanation seems shabby.

Currently in my code I have it set up so that when a certain condition happens, one of my movie clips from my library gets added to the stage, which is what I wanted. However in addition to this I'd like to use a button that is within that movie clip to reference another scene and send the user there, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be helpful, thanks!

Here's where I'm applying the code I mentioned above:

```
if(Sprite_Cannon_Char.alpha <= 0)
        {
            holder = new MovieClip();
            stage.addChild(holder);
            myAlert = new AlertB();
            holder.addChild(myAlert);
            holder.x = 250 - 190/3;
            holder.y = stage.height/2 - 125/2;
            //setChildIndex(AlertBox, numChildren-1);
            //AlertBox.visible = true;
            Espeedy = 0;
            Espeedx = 0;
            CBvelocity[i] = 0;

        }
```

Comment: If anyone wants me to upload my code just ask.

Comment: Sidenote: AlertB is linkage to my alert movie clip in the library.

Comment: Does your button inside `AlertB` have an instance name?   `myAlert.myButtonName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);`  then make a function called btnClick and in that go to your scene.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you didnt give any task to the movieclip named holder

```js
holder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,newFunc);
function newFunc(e:MouseEvent)
{
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2"); 
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean but I'm not trying to use the movie clip to go to the previous scene, I'm trying to use the button that is within the scene. So you answer is correct but not the one I need for my purposes.

Comment: maybe you should try to holder.myAlert.getChildByName("butonName").addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,newFunction);

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Do I need to add the button separately?